# Position caret/cursor inside newly added span in tiny mce

Tags: tinymce

I need to add a span at caret position in my application. I could add span  at caret position with following code, but could not position the caret inside it, so that if user types in it will go inside the new span.

```
marker = ed.selection.getBookmark();
ed.selection.moveToBookmark(marker);
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<span id="mytitle"></span>');
ed.selection.moveToBookmark(marker);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to place a cursor myself. You might need to modify it slightly to be used with the span you created, but this should put you intio the right direction:

```
// sets the cursor position to the defined node
// ed: editor, start: defines if the cursor is to be placed at the start or end of the node
// return node: boolean, if set returns the caretnode instead of deleting it
function setCursor(ed, node, start, return_node){

    tn = ed.getDoc().createTextNode(".");
    if (start){
    node.insertBefore(tn, node.firstChild);
    } 
    else node.appendChild(tn);

    rng = ed.selection.getRng();
    rng.selectNode(tn);
    rng.setStartBefore(tn);
    rng.setStartAfter(tn);

    ed.selection.setRng(rng);

    if (return_node) return tn;

    node.removeChild(tn);
}
```